# Unable to configure cloud provider (azure) with OpenShift Origin

Tags: azure, cloud, openshift, azure-storage, openshift-origin

I want to add a cloud provider (Azure)for my persistent volume storage (Azure File).
I have added Cloud Providers details in Inventory and run the prerequisites.yml from OpenShift-ansible and also run deploy_cluster.yml.

installation get done successfully and cloud provider details get automatically added into node-config.yml
but missing in master-config.yml.

if I add details manually in master-config.yml then it is giving me an error
i.e all the running images of dockers getting down.

and if I put master-config.yml without cloud provider details then it is working properly.

but failed to configure cloud-provider with OpenShift.

**The link which I have followed**
https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/install_config/configuring_azure.html

**Automatically generated**
kubeletArguments:
cloud-provider:
- "azure"
cloud-config:
- "/etc/azure/azure.conf"

**Error after adding**
kubernetesMasterConfig:
...
apiServerArguments:
cloud-provider:
- "azure"
cloud-config:
- "/etc/azure/azure.conf"
controllerArguments:
cloud-provider:
- "azure"
cloud-config:
- "/etc/azure/azure.conf"

**Version**
oc v3.9.0+71543b2-33
kubernetes v1.9.1+a0ce1bc657
features: Basic-Auth GSSAPI Kerberos SPNEGO

**Current Result**
Not Configured

**Expected Result**
Cloud Provider(azure) should get configured with OpenShift

Comment: Which step did you see an error in this document?
https://docs.okd.io/3.9/install_config/configuring_azure.html

More detailed error message is required to know what happens.

Comment: **Configuring Masters**

Edit or create the master configuration file on all masters (/etc/origin/master/master-config.yaml by default) and update the contents of the apiServerArguments and controllerArguments sections:

kubernetesMasterConfig:
  ...
  apiServerArguments:
    cloud-provider:
      - "azure"
    cloud-config:
      - "/etc/azure/azure.conf"
  controllerArguments:
    cloud-provider:
      - "azure"
    cloud-config:
      - "/etc/azure/azure.conf"

While performing this step I got an error in my installation.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: apiServerArguments: cloud-provider: - "azure" cloud-config: - "/etc/azure/azure.conf" controllerArguments: cloud-provider: - "azure" cloud-config: - "/etc/azure/azure.conf"